# Public-Key Authentication w/ Jailed SFTP User

Tags: networking, ssh, sftp, key-authentication, sshd

I'm trying to set up a jailed SFTP user account on my own local machine to test an application with libcurl. I used this guide to help me figure out how to set up a jailed SFTP user: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/chroot-sftp-setup/

The guide does work, but I'd like to set up public-key authentication to log in to the SFTP user's account instead of using a password. I have some basic understanding of generating and authorizing private and public keys from this guide: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/ssh-public-key-based-authentication-how-to.html

However, trying to add an authorized_keys2 directory in the sftp user's home directory doesn't seem to work. Any tips or advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a **directory** `authorized_keys2`, you need a directory `~/.ssh` and in that directory a **file** `authorized_keys2`.

Comment: Thanks, got that fixed. However, it still doesn't seem to work. I've copied the `id_rsa.pub` file from my main user to the `authorized_keys2` file in the `/sftp/sftpuser/incoming/.ssh` directory. When I try to connect through sftp it says "Connection reset by peer".

Comment: `authorized_keys2` shouldn't be used since it was deprecated twelve years ago. All keys should go into the `authorized_keys` file.

Comment: @sj755 What does the sshd log say?

Comment: @j883376 Changed the filename. Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @HaukeLaging /var/log/secure doesn't seem to mention anything about my attempted logins. All it mentions are my logins to root and me catting the /var/log/secure file itself.

Comment: Double-check permissions on `~/.ssh` - should be 700 and sometimes `authorizedkeys` file needs to be 600 permissions with some versions of SSH.